# iOS. UITextView. Text jumping after UIKeyboardDidHideNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I have editable UITextView and keyboard dismiss mode is interactive. Also my controller is listening two notifications: `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {


    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

            var insets = self.textView.contentInset;
            let rect = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue() ?? CGRectZero
            insets.bottom = (rect.size.height - (CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - CGRectGetMaxY(self.textView.frame)))
            self.textView.contentInset = insets
            self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
}


func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero 
}
```

This stuff works great, if text in UITextView doesn't contain any empty lines. If it do, `contentOffset` jumps to another, random place.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in iOS 7+, or I am doing something wrong.
If it's not a bug, how to get this going fluently without the jumping behaviour?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `contentOffset` jumps to random place?

Comment: @Mrunal after hiding  keyboard contentOffset is, for example, (0, 350). Superview call layoutSubviews and contentOffset jump  to point (0, -20) and after that (often) jump to (0,0)

Comment: Try overriding `layoutSubviews` method and check `contenOffset` value there.

Answer (score 2):

I had been battling this exact same problem, when I would dismiss the keyboard the UITextView's content offset would jump back to `{0, 0}`. Interestingly, I only got this behavior on the device, but not in the simulator.

I originally tried to solve it by overriding UITextView's `contentOffset` method and having it just ignore `{0, 0}` values, and that was semi effective, until the content got too long, in which case it would just jump to a random offset, and set the same value 3 times (so it would set content offset to `{0, 3605}`, `{0, 3605}`, and `{0, 3605}` all in rapid succession).

After a long time spent looking for a solution, it turned out to be rather simple:

```
textview.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = NO;
```

As discussed in [this blog post](http://justabunchoftyping.com/fix-for-ios7-uitextview-issues). Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had 100% exactly the same problem as you and I also asked a question about it but no one could get it right. (I am the one who up voted and favourited your question!!)

I eventually did a workaround after 4 days of frustration. Just put the `UITextView` inside a `UITableView` (You don't need to put it inside a `UITableViewCell`, just drag to the `UITableView` then it's ok). Make your `UITextView` unscrollable.

The following method will make UITextView expand and update the `UITableView` every time it is changed. (Don't forget to connect `UITextView's delegate`)

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    // Change textView height
    self.textView.sizeToFit()

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

The following method will make `UITableView` autoscroll to the cursor when `UITextView` becomes active.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    // Delay the following line so that it works properly
    let delay = 0.005 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        var rect = self.textView.caretRectForPosition(self.textView.selectedTextRange?.end)
        var changedRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.width, rect.height+3)

        self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(changedRect, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You also need to change the UITableView `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` in your `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` methods, depending on your screen layout.

Comment: surprisingly enough, your solution worked. I had to add some methods to adjust the size of the textview, to fill at least the full screen, and re-set the tableViewFooterView to enforce recalculating the content size, but it worked, and the jumps are gone